# Query the database with Rails where method with optional parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have index action that get parameters from url like `http://localhost:3000/api/budgets?marketplace_id=1&budget_year_id=3&vendor=pepsi&details=sugarfree` and use them to query the database with where method. But there are two parameters that are mandatory( `marketplace_id and budget_year_id`) and two more that are optional (`vendor and details`).For mandatory parameters i  can just do `Budget.where("marketplace_id=? and budget_year_id=?",params[:marketplace_id], params[:budget_year_id])` .My question is how would i query for optional parameters since they are might not always be there? Here is index action

```
def index
   unless params[:marketplace_id].blank? || params[:budget_year_id].blank?
      @budgets = Budget.where("marketplace_id=? and budget_year_id=?",params[:marketplace_id], params[:budget_year_id])# How do i add optional parameters ,vendor and/or details
      respond_with (@budgets)
   else
      render :json=>{:errors =>"Marketplace_id and Budget_year_id must be present",:status=>402}
   end
end
```

Comment: Try `@budgets = Budget.where("marketplace_id=? and budget_year_id=?",params[:marketplace_id], params[:budget_year_id]).where("vendor=? or details=?",params[:vendor],params[:details])`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but That didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional where clauses to your original query only if the optional parameters are present. The query won't be executed until you try to access the results of the query. For instance:

```
@budgets = Budget.where(marketplace_id: params[:marketplace_id], 
  budget_year_id: params[:budget_year_id])

@budgets = @budgets.where(vendor: params[:vendor]) if params[:vendor]
@budgets = @budgets.where(details: params[:details]) if params[:details]
```

Comment: how to do if more than 15 parameters are there in the query ?